# collect multiple data from view - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

**Question**

I want to retrieve multiple data from a view and store it into a **key:value** array in the controller.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">

     <input type="number" id = "{{element.id}}">

</div>
```

The array should contain **element.id** as the key and the value of the input as the value.

I checked angular docs but not found anything helpful to perform this task.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You are approaching this all wrong ... use `ng-model` to bind form controls to controller model. There are lots of angular form tutorials around...suggest studying them

Comment: I've tried it but i don't know how to retrieve the data

Comment: Use an object in `ng-model` and that object will be available in controller scope. Again...tutorials will explain this

Comment: Thanks it worked after adding ng-model="model[element.id]"